# Winforms ProgressBar Takes time to Render

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, progress-bar

I have noticied that when using the PorgressBar. If I set the value to x, the value displayed is not immediately updated, it takes a small amount of time to draw it as the bar is animated from its current value to the new value.

This is easy to see in the following code:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = ""
    Dim progressHandler = New Progress(Of Integer)(Sub(value) ProgressBar1.Value = value)
    Dim progress = CType(progressHandler, IProgress(Of Integer))
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       For i = 1 To 100
                           progress.Report(i)
                           Thread.Sleep(10)
                       Next
                   End Sub)
    Label1.Text = "Value Now at 100%"
    Await Task.Delay(650) 'it takes this long for the bar to be rendered
    Label1.Text += " - Finished drawing"
End Sub
```

You will notice running this code that the `Value Now at 100%` appears a long time before the bar has actually reached 100%.

Is there any way that I can detect when the bar has finished rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this out and can see exactly what you mean.  Unfortunately after spending a little while seeing if the DrawToBitmap functions on the progress bar might help, I've come up short.

The next step would be to create a custom progress bar that exposes events for when rendering has completed.

For a reasonable example on how to create a custom progress bar, try here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer(v=VS.100).aspx

A quick scan over the code looks like you should be able to plug in an 'OnRendered' event or similar on or around the calls to 'DrawHorizontalChunks' (or 'DrawVerticalChunks').

Probably not the answer you was after, but at least gives you the control you need if you pursue it?

Note: I haven't tried this myself, so please don't send me hate mail if you spend all day on this to find you get the same results...

Good Luck!

EDIT:

Wasn't happy with my response, seemed a bit lazy...  The following uses a custom progress bar as I described.  It has a couple basic properties for setting Max/Min values, Performing steps, and setting the value directly.  I've tested this by changing the sleep interval to various amounts, in all cases the form displayed the progress bar as full before closing.  Note the new OnRendered event.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles

Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Private WithEvents bar1 As ProgressBarWithRender = New ProgressBarWithRender()


    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Size = New Size(500, 500)
        bar1.Location = New Point(100, 100)
        bar1.Width = 300
        bar1.Height = 50
        bar1.Maximum = 30
        bar1.Step = 1
        Controls.Add(bar1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnRendered(ByVal valueRendered As Integer) Handles bar1.OnRendered
        If valueRendered = bar1.Maximum Then
            ' We know everything has been drawn
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub


    <STAThread()> _
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        ' The call to EnableVisualStyles below does not affect
        ' whether ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported is true; as 
        ' long as visual styles are enabled by the operating system, 
        ' IsSupported is true.
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.Run(New Form1())

    End Sub 'Main

    Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        For i = 1 To 30
            bar1.PerformStep()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class 'Form1

Public Class ProgressBarWithRender
    Inherits Control

    Public Delegate Sub RenderedEventArgs(ByVal valueRendered As Integer)
    Public Event OnRendered As RenderedEventArgs

    Private ProgressBarRectangles() As Rectangle

    Public Property [Step] As Integer

    Public Property InnerPadding As Integer = 3

    Private _Maximum As Integer
    Public Property Maximum As Integer
        Get
            Return _Maximum
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _Maximum = value
            CalculateTickSizes()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Minimum As Integer
    Public Property Minimum As Integer
        Get
            Return _Minimum
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _Minimum = value
            CalculateTickSizes()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Value As Integer
    Public Property Value As Integer
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
        Set(newValue As Integer)
            If newValue < Me.Value AndAlso newValue > 0 Then
                Throw New NotImplementedException("ProgressBarWithRender does not support decrementing the value")
            End If
            Me._Value = newValue
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub PerformStep()
        ' Ensure step doesn't exceed boundaries
        If Value + [Step] > Maximum Then
            Value = Maximum
        ElseIf Value + [Step] < Minimum Then
            Value = Minimum
        Else
            Value += [Step]
        End If

        ' We are limited by the Renderers Chunk Width, so we possibly can't draw every step if there is a high maximum
        Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
        ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalChunks(g, ProgressBarRectangles(Value - Minimum))
        RaiseEvent OnRendered(Value)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        If Not ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported Then
            Throw New NotImplementedException("Progress Bar Rendering is not supported")
        End If
        ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateTickSizes()
        ' Changing the Maximum will change the tick rectangle size
        ProgressBarRectangles = New Rectangle(Maximum) {}
        Dim chunkThickness As Integer = ProgressBarRenderer.ChunkThickness + (ProgressBarRenderer.ChunkSpaceThickness * 2)
        Dim tickThickness As Double = ((ClientRectangle.Width - (InnerPadding * 2)) - (ProgressBarRenderer.ChunkSpaceThickness * 2)) / (Maximum - Minimum)
        If tickThickness < chunkThickness Then
            Debug.Print("This will go wrong because we can't draw small enough chunks...")
        End If
        For i As Integer = 0 To Maximum
            Dim filledRectangle As Integer = CInt(tickThickness * i)
            ProgressBarRectangles(i) = New Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X + InnerPadding,
                                                     ClientRectangle.Y + InnerPadding,
                                                     filledRectangle,
                                                     ClientRectangle.Height - (InnerPadding * 2))
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: +1 and marked as the answer - thanks for the full solution, but I think this is a little over complex for what it is doing. I have worked around this issue by starting a stopwatch and waiting until 600ms after the last step change before quitting, allow the progressbar time to move to the required 100%

Comment: Much simpler solution, I don't blame you.  Thanks for the feedback.  I'll contemplate whether it's worth raising an MS request on the connect site or similar, for a similar post rendering event available from the standard progress bar .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're in a single threaded program and the thread needs time to update the display.

Add the line

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

Before closing the `UpdateProgress` sub.

And you can get rid of the last two refresh.

Comment: DoEvents will actually perform the two refreshes AND any other refreshes that are required, so this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed. What you're forgetting to take into consideration is that if you close the splash screen right after finishing the loading process you miss the human delay time in recognizing movement. Any movement faster than 1/24s is imperceptible.

Comment: Hence the question - "Is there some event I can use to find out when the progress bar has finished redrawing?" - It seems that when changing Value or calling PerformStep the progress bar does not move directly to that value, it animates through all values from Old -> New and this takes a finite amount of time, therefore when my app ends it has not finished animating to the new value yet. DoEvents does not fix this issue.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's so much the human delay.  I haven't tried, but I'd place a friendly bet that if you run some form of screen recording using Matt's example (or one with no thread sleeping) and then played the recording back one frame at a time, the progress bar doesn't actually render the itself as being full/max value before closing the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code based on Matt Wilko's suggestion:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
Dim client As New WebClient
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    AddHandler client.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadStringCompleted
    AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_DownloadProgressChanged

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    client.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://somewebsite.com"), Nothing)
End Sub
Private Sub client_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    If ProgressBar1.Value < e.ProgressPercentage Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub client_DownloadStringCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static waitToCloseProgressBar As Integer
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        If waitToCloseProgressBar > 6 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            waitToCloseProgressBar = 0
            ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        Else
            waitToCloseProgressBar = waitToCloseProgressBar + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I have good results with progressbar lag, setting the value with this function:

```
Private Sub SetProgressNoAnimation(ByVal value As Integer)
    ' To get around the progressive animation, we need to move the 
    ' progress bar backwards.
    If (value = progressBarCarga.Maximum) Then
        ' Special case as value can't be set greater than Maximum.
        progressBarCarga.Maximum = (value + 1)
        ' Temporarily Increase Maximum
        progressBarCarga.Value = (value + 1)
        ' Move past
        progressBarCarga.Maximum = value
        ' Reset maximum
    Else
        progressBarCarga.Value = (value + 1)
        ' Move past
    End If
    progressBarCarga.Value = value
    ' Move to correct value
End Sub
```

More information:

https://derekwill.com/2014/06/24/combating-the-lag-of-the-winforms-progressbar/

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem.
I would prefer to sue the standard progress bar  in order to have a typical design in the application.

It is true that it needs time to update, and since DoEvents does not work on its own, I would recommend to do the loading by using a backgroundworker. When finished and it still doesn't work, then either add a doevents, or a small delay. But I guess your solution to ad a delay of 100ms would be best, since it requirest the fewest changes and is still working. what about just adding 10ms delay to it.
The other way would be: try progressBar.Invalidate  (force a repaint), add code to paint, which checks if paint is executed, and then close the form. I guess DoEvents won't work in paint, since paint needs to finish. so you could enabl a timer with 100ms interval and it would close the window.

about everything less 1/24s is invisible for humans is bu..sh..
there are liquids in the eye which see even mcuh shorter things. It is a difference if we can immediately react to something, but since the information is 'burned' on the surface of the eyes until it will be 'read' by nerves, it is not lost. there are even problems with 60Hz, and I am sure most people know that annoying 60Hz crt problem. LCD does not flicker that intense, but if you need a high framerate, and 60 is not enough, then you can still 'see' the problems with 60 and it looks mcuh better with 100 or higher.

Comment: are you asking a question, offering an answer, or simply commenting?

Answer (score -1):

I found that using PerformStep() instead of setting the value did not have this rendering delay - still had to call Application.DoEvents() though.

Answer (score -2):

I got an acceptable result by inserting 
frmMain.Refresh
after assigning a new value to the standard ProgressBar.