# datagridview to excel - progressbar vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, progress-bar

I have a button that let's me export a datagridview to excel. Sometimes it has more than 5000 rows, so it takes a bit longer.

I tried to add a progress bar, but it is simply random ( the way it is below).
How can i implement the progressbar in a better way ? i don't think i need the timer anyway .

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
    Dim xlPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "template.xlsx")
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    'Dim rTargetCell As Excel.Range
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

'TEST!
For i = 0 To i = ProgressBar1.Maximum
    ProgressBar1.Value = i
    ProgressBar1.Update()
    Timer2.Start()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25)
    Next
'End Test!

xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("data")

    For i = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count

                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView2(j, i).Value
            Next
        Next
    Next
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\User\Desktop\" & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    Process.Start("C:\Users\User\Desktop\" & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx")
    Me.Close()
  End Sub


Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    Label3.Text = "(...)"
    If ProgressBar1.Maximum = DataGridView2.Rows.Count Then
    Label3.Text = "Finished"
    End If
    Timer2.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217894/vb-net-progress-bar

Comment: where does that help me mate? honest question here

Comment: @codeMonger123 i mean, if i do that the progressbar stops a bit before the maximum. i guess it doesn't englobe the SaveAs ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your progress bar is from min value 0 to max value 100. You should divide the row you are about to dump into excel by 100.

e.g under this line `For i = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1`

put this line `ProgressBar1.Value = Int(i * (ProgressBar1.Maximum / DataGridView2.RowCount))`
Then under that put this line to make sure the view updates, as you are not running the progress bar updates on a separate thread.`My.Application.DoEvents()`

So it should look like this

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1

   ProgressBar1.Value = Int(i * (ProgressBar1.Maximum / DataGridView2.RowCount))
    My.Application.DoEvents()

    For j = 0 To DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1
        For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView2(j, i).Value
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: ye i know. but what about the "SaveAs" ? it takes time to .. sometimes more than 60sec.. and yet the progressbar is already complete

Comment: The progress bar is not showing the time it takes to save the file. The progress bar is showing how far along the routine has written the datagrid values to the excel sheet.
If you need to display a progress bar or something whilst your application or the excel control takes to save the file, you may need to look at saving the file from another thread.

Comment: and is that possible using the code i have so far? cause i don't see how the xlApp communicates from another thread. or to another thread.

Comment: So the progress bar is functioning how it should. The problem is your save time may vary could you try this :
`Dim dt As String = DateTime.Now.ToString()` 
`xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\User\Desktop\" & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx")` 
`MsgBox(DateTime.Now.ToString() & " " & dt)`
just to see how long this operation is taking and if it is this operation, and then maybe you can find out why.

Comment: well, you might be right. it's something before.. it took less than 1sec to the operation to complete..

Comment: You should implement this method, to help debug where the application is hanging, weed out some of the code that you do not need e.g testing code. Once you have found what could be causing the slow down, you might be able to rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: well i forgot that i had another method running after inserting the rows in the excel.. this way i changed my progressbar.maximum ( action1 + action2 + saveas ) and it worked fine ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the below. before you start the loop you can set the progressbar maximum value to the total number or records you have.

```
me.progressbar1.maximum = DataGridView2.RowCount 


For i = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
    For j = 0 To DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1
        For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView2(j, i).Value
        Next
    Next
Me.ProgressBar1.performstep()  'increment your bar with each record
Next
```

Comment: that's what i did. but that way, after the progressbar is complete, the "task" is still not complete, like the SaveAs..

Comment: I see, okay, what if you made the maximum + 1 record of your data and then right after me.close you increment the progress step by 1 which would complete the progress bar.

Comment: i thought about it too. yet the action of saving requires a few seconds, depending on the number of rows. sometimes more than 1min, and it's kinda weird seeing the bar almost complete, but stopped for more than a "few" secs..

Comment: Right, but if you were to increment the progress bar by 1 after closing excel the time it takes to save shouldnt matter....Unless I am missing something.

Comment: you are not missing anything mate! i guess you just don't understand how important it is to "resize" the progressbar. it's like i had a 1min countdown, but the countdown would be actually 2mins.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have only two possibilities : You make your method run a lot of time and you calculate the average time it takes, then you add that time to your progress bar, or you write your own method to know where you're at saving the file...

Comment: i figured out it wasn't the SaveAs that was taking the time .. see the other answer ! thank you